# Kafka - What happens if the message that the subscribing consumer should read is deleted?

Tags: apache-kafka

**I wonder what would happen in the following situation.**

1. The value of the offset that the subscribing consumer should read is 7.
2. Stop the consumer.
3. 20 new messages coming in.
4. Offset messages less than 10 are removed.
5. Run the consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer will seek back to the `auto.offset.reset` value